# How do I add a decimal to my number?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm doing some calculations and I end up with `65.0` or `43.5`.
I need to add a zero to this number so that my number comparison  works:

`$this->sub_total == $order_sub_total`

I've tested using number_format():

```
$total = number_format($total, 2, '.');
```

But that gives me er msg: `Wrong parameter count for number_format()`

I'm tempted to just do:

```
$total = $total.'0';
```

But I think that is a bad idea in case the number is `35.43`.

So how can I add a extra decimal to my number?

Comment: If you mention the decimal separator, you have to also use the thousands separator.

Comment: @matt Thanks, I didn't know that. I've read the documentation, but it's not always as easy to understand :)

Comment: @Dale some regions use `,` as the decimal separator, so `number_format($total, 2)` isn't universally correct. To be sure that OP gets the result he wants, he must use `number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');`.

Answer (score 25):

With [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) you need either two or four parameters. Three will always through an error.

For you both of the following will work identically:

```
$total = number_format($total, 2);

$total = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
```

Comment: Thanks. As @dale also suggested, just using `number_format($total, 2)`worked like a charm. And now I understand how number_format works :)

Answer (score 4):

If you mention the decimal separator, you have to also use the thousands separator.

So either do

```
number_format($total, 2);
```

OR

```
number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
```

[Here's the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Since some regions use `,` as the decimal separator, so `number_format($total, 2)` isn't universally correct. To be sure that you get the result you want, you must use `number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a plain old `$total = sprintf("%01.2f", $total)` ?

Edit:

1 million iterations timing with `$n = 3.14159`:

```
$total = sprintf("%01.2f", $n);               9.148s
$total = number_format($n, 2);                8.296s
$total = number_format($n, 2, ".", ",");     10.944s
```

So `sprintf` is slightly better than a full-fledged `number_format` with separators.

Comment: Because `number_format()` makes your intent clear without having to comment?

Comment: 1 million iterations timing with $n = 3.14159:

    $total = sprintf("%01.2f", $n);               9.148s
    $total = number_format($n, 2);                8.296s
    $total = number_format($n, 2, ".", ",");     10.944s

So `sprintf` is slightly better than a full-fledged `number_format` with separators.

Comment: `faster` != `better` but I understand your point. When it comes to *maintainability* I prefer seeing code that immediately expresses the author's intent, rather than code that saves 2 seconds on 1 million iterations.

Comment: One point for *maintainability*. But I've grown accustomed to associating PHP with "code that runs on a server with potentially millions of customers in realtime" and thus strive to provide the best *performance* when it comes to code. I tried again with a large number with 4 or 5 thousands-separators, and it takes approx. 1.4x the time.

Comment: That's a great point. First I was just answering your rhetorical "why not", then I had to clarify. Cheers!